# build_http_query Array of Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple variable

```
$body = array(
        'content' => 'content test',
        'is_sanitize' => true,
        'sanitize_replacement' => '***',
        'meta' => array(
                    'name' => 'another',
                    'email' => 'another@email.com'
                )
    );
```

When i use `build_http_query($body)`, it give me

```
content=content%20test&is_sanitize=1&meta=another&meta=another%40email.com&sanitize_replacement=%2A%2A%2A
```

the question is where the 'name' and 'email' key ? why build_http_query not add those key ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [result](http://codepad.viper-7.com/f2TYtO) should be:

```
content=content+test&is_sanitize=1&sanitize_replacement=%2A%2A%2A&meta%5Bname%5D=another&meta%5Bemail%5D=another%40email.com
```

Note: not `build_http_query` but `http_build_query`.

Comment: hoo i c. now i understand. Thank You xdazz

Comment: Although true, this should be a comment, it doesn't explain what happens to those keys.